# C++ socket only sends first 4 bytes of data

Tags: c++, sockets

I am currently writing a socket wrapper in C++ for Linux. It is basically a collection of classes that handle the creation, connection, sending, reading, and closing of a TCP socket.

In my socket class, all functions work well except for the send and receive function. They do not return an error; instead, it only sends the first four bytes of data.

My send function:

```
int Socket::sends(char* buffer){

    int bytes; // for number of bytes sent

    /* First, send the size of buffer */
    int datalen = strlen(buffer); // get sizeof buffer
    int len     = htonl(datalen); // reformat

    // send the size of the buffer
    bytes = send(socketfd, (char*)&len, sizeof(len), 0); // send the size
    if (bytes < 0){
        cerr << "Error sending size of buffer to socket" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Now acutally send the data */

    bytes = send(socketfd, buffer, datalen, 0);
    if (bytes < 0){
        cerr << "Error writing buffer to socket" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << bytes << " written" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

The ideas behind it is that It sends the buffer (`char* buffer`) by first sending the size of the buffer, and then sending the actual buffer. If an error is encountered (returning -1) the function terminates by returning 1.

Now, here is the read method:

```
 int Socket::reads(char* buffer){

    int bytes, buflen; // for bytes written and size of buffer

    /* Read the incoming size */
    bytes = recv(socketfd, (char*)&buflen, sizeof(buflen), 0);
    if (bytes < 0){
        cerr << "Error reading size of data" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    buflen = ntohl(buflen);

    /* Read the data */

    bytes = recv(socketfd, buffer, buflen, 0);
    if (bytes < 0){
        cerr << "Error reading data" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the idea is to read the size of the data first, and then set the buffer to that size and read into it. The function returns 1 on error (recv returns -1).

Using the methods would look something like this:

```
socket.sends("Hello World"); // socket object sends the message

char* buffer;
socket.reads(buffer); // reads into the buffer
```

However, when ever I use these functions, I only receive the first 4 bytes of data, followed by strange, non-ASCII characters. I have no idea why this happens. No error is not encountered in the `send` and `recv` functions, and the functions say that only 4 bytes were written. Is there a better way that I should send or receive data? I am overlooking a very simple error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages. Please only use the relevant tag.

Comment: How do you know that there is enough memory allocated for the read?  The sample code creates a pointer named `buffer`, but doesn't point it at any allocated memory.

Comment: If you're using a nonblocking socket, `recv` may read any number of bytes including 0, you need to call `recv` until you have all the data or an error is returned.

Comment: `int datalen = strlen(buffer); // get sizeof buffer` this looks fishy

Comment: `char* buffer;
socket.reads(buffer);` is that your real code or did you "simplify" it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're passing an uninitialized pointer (`buffer`) to your `reads` method, which probably explains that it works partially (undefined behaviour).

And you shouldn't pass `buffer` as a parameter since it won't be modified (and you don't know the size yet anyway)

Plus, you have to null-terminate your message when you recieve it.

I would do like this:

```
 char *Socket::reads(){
    char* buffer;
    int bytes, buflen; // for bytes written and size of buffer

    /* Read the incoming size */
    bytes = recv(socketfd, (char*)&buflen, sizeof(buflen), 0);
    if (bytes < 0){
        cerr << "Error reading size of data" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    buflen = ntohl(buflen);
    buffer = new char[buflen+1]; // +1 for the NUL-terminator
    /* Read the data */

    bytes = recv(socketfd, buffer, buflen, 0);
    if (bytes < 0){
        cerr << "Error reading data" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    buffer[buflen] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate the string

    return buffer;
}
```

the main:

```
socket.sends("Hello World"); // socket object sends the message

char* buffer = socket.reads(); // reads into the buffer
```

don't forget to `delete []` the buffer in the end.

Could also be done with `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` to avoid `new` and `delete`

Comment: This is good advice, but if OP's `buffer` is big enough, there is no UB. It is not uninitialized, it is presumably allocated and then passed to the function.

Comment: you may be right. Maybe I answered too soon to be sure. The null-termination part I'm sure of. You get garbage if you don't null terminate since it's not sent, even if buffer is large enough.

Comment: `buffer` is clearly uninitialized when `socket.reads(buffer);` occurs in the code at the end of the OP.

Comment: I thought that too. But what alain meant is that it may be a non-representative `main`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh I didn't notice that `main` .. you're right, +1.

Comment: @alain thanks. The silence of the OP is unbearable though :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Less creepy than The Silence of the Lambs, though.

Comment: Yes. I first thought a nonblocking socket could be the problem, but the OP didn't answer that either. Lol @user4581301

Comment: if you don't do anything special TCP defaults to blocking IIRC. but you're right. Prepare to downvote my post if it's non-blocking :) but that would be bad luck: non-blocking and wrong main function pasted with uninitialized buffer...

Comment: Yes that's what I remember too. I'm going to sleep now and I can't downvote tomorrow since I upvoted now... But anyway, the chances that I get hit by a meteorite are bigger than that what you just said is true.. :-)

Comment: Better default to blocking or I've been writing really dangerous code for years.